# How to scale/rotate/move an asset in OpenSceneGraph

Tags: c++, openscenegraph

I am totally new with OpenSceneGraph

I can open and save an OSG asset.
I need to do some simple transformations on it, like dimension scaling/rotation/translation.

It seems a pretty easy task, anyway I can't find any quick documentation :/

```
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Node> rectangle = osgDB::readNodeFile("../../inputs/Rectangle.osg");

// define simple transformation matrix
// apply  simple trnasformation matrix

osgDB::writeNodeFile(*rectangle, "../../outputs/saved.osg");
```

Any hint?

Comment: If you download the [latest stable source](http://www.openscenegraph.org/index.php/download-section/stable-releases) you'll find many examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use class osg::MatrixTransform, see for instance [this example](https://github.com/openscenegraph/OpenSceneGraph/blob/274938e3c5d1a2c63afcf884ba4475c9654bc1a0/examples/osganimate/osganimate.cpp#L148)